# How Do I Implement Search Like Feature For NodeJS App Which Using ArangoJS(ArangoDB)

Tags: node.js, arangojs

{
    sno : "1",
    name: "abc",
    comment1: "dd cdt djdhj",
    myComment: "adt dtt cdt abc"
}

{
    sno : "2",
    name: "adc",
    comment1: "dd ddt djdhj",
    myComment: "adt t cdt abc"
}

{
    sno : "3",
    name: "ab",
    comment1: "dd cdt djdhj",
    myComment: "cdt abc"
}

{
    sno : "4",
    name: "ddt",
    comment1: "dd cdt djdhj",
    myComment: "adt dtt"
}

I have data stored like the above shown in collection named users in ArangoDB

If i search for query "dtt" it should return all documents which contains query str ..

How To Do This **Using ArangoJS** (Just as simple search feature in an NodeJS Application)

I want to know is there any built-in feature is available in ArangoJS just like MongoDB's find() method.

Answer (score 0):

For no nested structure in the json document this can be done.

```
for (key in jsonDoc){
    var value = jsonDoc[key];
    if (key.toString().indexOf(searchstr) != -1  || value.toString().indexOf(searchstr) != -1){
        FOUND A MATCH
    }
```

If there is a nested structure in the json , you will have to use a traversal method. Search for "Traversing Json" and implement the same concept as above

Comment: is there any simple method available in ArangoJS ? Just like MongoDB's find() method.. I want to know how to accomplish above with ArangoJS built-in methods.. Not with explicit JS code...

Comment: `string.indexOf("search-string")` is the best thing for searching existence of any sub string in the main string

Comment: I'm not asking for js way of searching... i am seeing for ArangoJS method which can do search operation by leveraging in-built search available in ArangoDb(if available)... just like mongodb's find() method..